# How to filter nested object when using include Entity Framework core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have a **user** table that contains a nested table named **UserPriviliges** in this table I have **isDeleted** field to identify deleted data without actually deleting it, I want to retrieve a user with its privilege  using include

```
 public async Task<User> GetUser(Guid userId)
    {
        return await RepositoryContext.Users
            .Include(x => x.UserPrivileges).ThenInclude(x => x.Privilege)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId);
    }
```

how to filter **UserPriviliges** to bring only items with false **isDeleted** property

in EF Core <3.0 I could do it like this

```
 return await RepositoryContext.Users
            .Include(x => x.UserPrivileges.Where(y=>y.IsDeleted)).ThenInclude(x => x.Privilege)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId);
```

but its not working any more in EF Core 3.1 it returns

> Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't remember this working in EF Core at all; and usually we would separate this into two queries: 1- fetch the user data, 2- fetch the filtered user privileges

```
var user = await RepositoryContext.Users
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId);

await RepositoryContext.UserPrivileges
    .Where(up => up.UserId == userId && !up.IsDeleted)
    .Include(up => up.Privilege)
    .ToListAsync();

return user;
```

When we bring related data into the context with the 2nd query, ef will take care of populating user.UserPrivileges, so we don't need to assign it at all. This works well if we fetch multiple user data.

Comment: Thanks this works altho won't this increases the requests on the database?

Comment: Yes it does, so you end up with 2 requests but they have less joins.

Answer (score 0):

One option is :

```
public async Task<User> GetUser(Guid userId)
{
    return await RepositoryContext.Users
        .Include(x => x.UserPrivileges).ThenInclude(x => x.Privilege)
        .Where(x => x.UserPrivileges.Any(p => p.IsDeleted)) 
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId);
}
```

But this will return user with all the UserPrivileges (meaning returned User object will contain both IsDeleted and !IsDeleted UserPrivileges ).

if you have User reference in UserPrivileges, then another option is navigate from UserPrivileges something like below:

```
RepositoryContext.UserPrivileges
        .Include(x => x.User)
        .Where(x => x.IsDeleted && x.User.Id == userId)
```

Comment: I tried first one before asking and as you said it returns all privileges so it's not a solution, the second one does not work for me cause it will return privilege model not user model and the privileges inside it, i need the user model because i have other lists inside it that needs to be returned as well so this won't serve me

Comment: then before returning User object (using the first option), you need to do something like `user.UserPrivileges = user.UserPrivileges.Where(p => p.IsDeleted)` then return this user.